# Arranging centered multiple nav-tabs neatly in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was wondering, if there's any way to neatly arrange the nav-tabs in bootstrap 3.3.7 when there are many of them. The border at the bottom gets displaced and the active tab doesn't look very nice.

[image]

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
<li><a href="javascript:void()" data-toggle="tab">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void()">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void()">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void()">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void()">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void()">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void()">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.nav-tabs {
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
background: linear-gradient(#fff 50%, #fbfbfb 95%, #f3f3f3);
text-align: center;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
float:none;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: -1px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
padding: 6px 12px;
background: linear-gradient(#f2f4fc, #e1e5f4 95%, #e1e5f4);
border: 1px solid #ced5f1;
border-right-color: #bcc4e2;
border-bottom: none;
box-shadow: #fff 3px 1px 12px -4px inset;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
color: #000;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
color: #555555;
background: #ffffff;
cursor: default;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active {
border-bottom: transparent 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"neatly arrange"_? That's kind of subjective. Will the tabs always have the words "Lorem Ipsum" in them, because if not that will affect the width and/or height and _"neatly arrange"_ could be interrupted different. Flexbox might be your friend here.

Comment: The tabs will have different words in them and there will be many tabs. I don't mind about the width of each tab. I meant neatly, as in them being stacked not on top of the border on screen resize as in the picture.

Comment: You can expect that from horizontally placed tabs when there are too many to fit in a given width. Consider using vertical tabs if you're planning to have too many to fit horizontally. e.g: https://dbtek.github.io/bootstrap-vertical-tabs/demo.html

Comment: @Kaori So you don't want them to wrap to a new line? You want them to never stack correct?

Comment: @zgood I'm ok with them stacking as long as they look ok. I made them turn into buttons on small screens with media (max-width: 480px). But I wanted them to stack as tabs on other screen sizes.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError placing them vertically takes up more space so it's not an option, I guess. But thanks!